# Механизм добавления новых настроек в админке wp и корректный рендеринг

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть следующий код:

```
$tabs = array(
  'vk',
  'facebook',
  'instagram'
);

$saved = false;
if(isset($_POST['plugin_hidden']) && $_POST['plugin_hidden'] == 'Y') {
  $plugin_source_tabs = $_POST['plugin_source_tabs'];
  update_option('plugin_source_tabs', $plugin_source_tabs);
  $saved = true;
} else {
  $plugin_source_tabs = get_option('plugin_source_tabs', $tab_defaults);
}
?>

<?php if ($saved): ?>
<div class="updated"><p><strong><?php _e('Options saved.' ); ?></strong></p></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo "<h2>" . __( 'Plugin', 'plugin_settings' ) . "</h2>"; ?>
<form name="oscimp_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace('%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="plugin_hidden" value="Y">
    <h3>Options</h3>
    <p>
    <h3>Source tabs</h3>
    <select name="plugin_source_tabs[]" multiple="" size="3" style="width: 120px;">
        <?php
            $selected = in_array('all', $plugin_source_tabs) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
            echo '<option ' . $selected . ' value="all">All tabs</option>';
            foreach ($tabs as $tab) {
                $selected = in_array($tab, $plugin_source_tabs) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                echo '<option ' . $selected . ' value="' . $tab . '">' . $tab . '</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <p class="submit">
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </p>
</form>
```

Скажите, есть ли внутренний механизм добавления новых настроек в админке wp и корректный рендеринг? Хочу провести рефакторинг, а то, по незнанию нюансов wp, может выйти плохо.

Может, можно как-то "красиво" отделить логику от вывода тегов?

Comment: можешь написать свой модуль или плагин и пускать туда все, что хочешь

Comment: Не в этом вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, так делается во всех плагинах.
Корректного же разделения нет.